# Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session. problem debug

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have problem

```
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.distribution_system | com.example.distribution_system.test

Waiting for application to come online: com.example.distribution_system | com.example.distribution_system.test

Waiting for application to come online: com.example.distribution_system | com.example.distribution_system.test

--->Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
```

I did

--->adb kill-server && adb start-server

--->invalidate cache / restart

but not work yet

image1:--> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZF5D.png

image2:--> [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrE4a.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I was able to solve this by setting `android:exported = "true"` for the first Activity to launch.

```
<activity
     android:name = ".ui.top.TopActivity"
     android:exported = "true"
     android:label = "@string/app_name">

     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </ intent-filter>
</ activity>
```